# можно ли не указывать расширение js файлов

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Я только что начал изучать Node Js. Когда скачивал готовый проект я увидел что в папке bin находится файл с именем "www" без расширение. Но в нем написан JS скрипты. Оказывается package nodemon запускает это фай с помощью командой "npm run start". Я удивлен. Проект работает нормально.
Вопрос так: можно ли не указывать расширение js файлов

Comment: расширение файла нужно только для ассоциации с ним какой-либо программы, которая может его использовать. Самой программе безразлично наличие либо отсутствие расширения, важно лишь наличие файла по указанному адресу.

Comment: @Grundy Не всегда безразлично. Из личного опыта: Word отказывается открывать docx-файлы по WebDAV, если у них нет расширения .docx

Comment: @Yaant, а если просто file->open? Кстати, пишет какую-то конкретную ошибку?

Comment: @Grundy Через File->Open работает, но нам надо было запускать word и открывать файл по клику на ссылке в браузере. А пишет просто - "Произошла неожиданная ошибка".

Comment: Допустим создаем файл с html элементами. И указыаем расширени как txt. Потом открываем с помощью браузера. Этот момент мы увидим как текст а не как веб страниц. Не так ли. Или только браузер так читает.

Comment: @user8992487, браузер, в основном, ориентируется на mimeType, а не на расширение :-)

Comment: Понятно. Например text/html да